# Facebook Debugger Returning "Document returned no data"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently I noticed that Facebook's Object Debugger was unable to scrape any pages of my website. After troubleshooting and scouring the internet, I'm at a loss for what might be causing this bug.

Whenever I attempt to fetch a new scrape of my website, the following error is returned:

> Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.

When clicking into "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL", the scraper returns:

> Document returned no data

This is obviously a bit difficult to debug given the lack of data. Here's what I've tried thus far:

- Checked DNS settings, everything seems fine
- Tried using "Fetch as Google," GoogleBot had no problem fetching the page HTML
- Verified all the meta settings on the site. `fb:app_id`, `og:title`, `og:description`, `og:site_name`, `og:url`, and `og:type` are all present.
- Made sure canonical URL references the homepage, and does not have any trailing slash or trailing data.
- Rolled back commits to before the last successful crawl date

I'm at a loss for what could be causing this. If anyone has any ideas, or needs more information, I would be happy to provide it.

After checking access logs, I see the following:

> 173.252.112.115 - - [22/Jun/2015:20:49:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 993 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1
>   (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"

But this is strange, as it is immediately followed by a normal user:

> [user ip] - - [22/Jun/2015:20:48:09 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 28227
>   "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7"

There is nothing in robots.txt to disallow bots.

EDIT: This site is running on Django, and AngularJS is serving my pages. I'm using django-seo-js to work with prerender to improve SEO.

Comment: Can you give as the URL to an actual page? Have you checked your server’s access and error logs, for the timestamp where you triggered a scrape? Does the request from the FB scraper even reach your server?

Comment: The url is https://taggler.com ; I'm going to look into the access logs and I'll report back

Comment: It appears to register in my access log when I request a scrape. `173.252.112.115 - - [22/Jun/2015:20:49:02 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 993 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"`
Looks like it's hitting a 404? We have some logs that indicate there were also 200 responses.

Comment: Yes, when I visit your page in Chrome and send `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)` as value of the `User-Agent` header, I get a 404 as well (I used ModHeader extension for that), whereas requests with my normal Chrome User-Agent show me your start page just fine. So investigate if you have any plugins, “firewall” rules or similar set up to fight requests by “bots” – might be something is a little overzealous in that regard when it comes to visits from the FB scraper.

Comment: Yeah...it's throwing a Javascript stack trace. This seems like it might be getting caused by prerender. Thanks for the help - feel free to post your response and I can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I visit your page in Chrome and send `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)` as value of the `User-Agent` header, I get a 404 as well (I used ModHeader extension for that), whereas requests with my normal Chrome User-Agent show me your start page just fine.

<del>So investigate if you have any plugins, “firewall” rules or similar set up to fight requests by “bots” – might be something is a little overzealous in that regard when it comes to visits from the FB scraper.</del>
That doesn’t seem to be it though (was an educated guess only, since this is often the cause of such problems), but as you said,

> it's throwing a Javascript stack trace. This seems like it might be getting caused by prerender

– let us know if you found the exact cause.

Comment: This is indeed the case. Facebook bot's user-agent is sent to the our `?_escaped_fragment_= ` URL, which is in turn throwing an error with prerender.io. A ticket is in to prerender to determine the cause of this 404.

Comment: As it turns out, this was caused by a faulty nginx server. After rebuilding a new server, everything is back to normal.

Comment: @ZackTanner can you elaborate on that point, I think I have the same issue.